# Problema ao utilizar isNaN

Tags: javascript

Olá, eu criei um script que consome uma API pública de consultar ceps e retorna o resultado em um HTML.

O código:

```
async function buscarCEP() {

   let numeroCep = document.querySelector('.numeroCEP')
   numeroCep.value = parseInt(numeroCep.value)

   if (isNaN(numeroCep.value)) {
       alert('Digite apenas números sem traços,pontos,letras ou símbolos');
       return location.reload();
   }
   else {
       let cep = await fetch(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${numeroCep.value}/json/`);
       let resultado = await cep.json();
       retornarHtml(resultado)
   }

}

function retornarHtml(resultado) {
   let html = ''
   html += `<b> Rua: </b> ${resultado.logradouro} <br/> <br/>`
   html += `<b>Bairro: </b> ${resultado.bairro} <br/> <br/>`
   html += `<b>CEP: </b> ${resultado.cep} <br/> <br/>`
   html += `<b>Cidade: </b>${resultado.localidade} <br/> <br/>`
   html += `<b>Estado: </b>${resultado.uf} <br/> <br/>`
   html += `<b>DDD: </b> ${resultado.ddd} <br/> <br/>`
   document.querySelector('.resultadoPesquisa').innerHTML = html
   document.querySelector('.resultadoPesquisa').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Acontece o seguinte: Caso eu digitar no input: a54a54aa4, a minha condição é satisfeita e executa o código do if

Agora se eu faço: 1aa587a87a, ele apaga tudo, fica só o número 1 e a condição não é satisfeita

Bati cabeça por muito tempo e não consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na documentação do `parseInt()` explica o porquê disso: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

> Se parseInt encontrar um caracter que não seja um numeral na base
> especificada, ele o ignora e a todos os caracteres subsequentes e
> retorna o valor inteiro analisado até aquele ponto. parseInt trunca
> números para valores inteiros. Espaços no início e fim são permitidos.

Ou seja, se começar com um dígito, é convertido até que encontre algo inválido, e o restante é desprezado, exemplos:

```js
// primeiro caractere inválido, Nan
console.log(parseInt("!1a5b")); 
console.log(parseInt("a1a5b")); 
console.log(parseInt("x1a5b"));

// primeiro caracter válido, converte tudo, ou até encontrar um inválido, o resto é ignorado
console.log(parseInt("1!1a5b")); 
console.log(parseInt("12a1a5b")); 
console.log(parseInt("123x1a5b"));
```

Comment: Qual seria uma opção viável para que eu arrume meu código ? obrigado pelo feed

Comment: use um *regular expression* para verificar se só tem digitos, por exemplo `/^[0-9]+$/.test("123")`, no seu codigo `if(!/^[0-9]+$/.test(numeroCep.value))`

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa. Eu teria que modificar algo no código que você me passou, no caso esse .test ?? Desculpa a ignorância pois ainda não manjo de regex.

Comment: então deve estar fazendo algo de errado no if ou no input, olha esse exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/htcmfz67/

Comment: Deu certo...no lugar de parseInt eu coloquei Number...muito obrigado

Comment: @AyrtonGomes cuidado. `Number('123.3213')` dará certo, mas você quer um número inteiro...

Comment: @RafaelTavares, o regex vai pegar, ele só aceita digitos, mas foi bem notado isso do Number :) Aliás, nem precisa dessa conversão se vai passar o parâmetro para a API

Comment: @AyrtonGomes remova esse Number, não vai usar o número para cálculo nenhum, se é só pra validar o regex já vai fazer isso

Comment: O regex não estava validando com o parseInt...estava tendo o mesmo problema de apagar as strings e manter o primeiro número

Comment: *"O regex não estava validando com o parseInt"* como eu comentei acima, **não precisa desse paerseint**, basta o regex pra validar, você não precisar do valor como número, não precisa de parseint nem number

Comment: Desculpe, foi falta de atenção da minha parte...removi o Number e funciona normalmente. Muito obrigado